# Is there an actual expansion of the Gamma function's integral?

Tags: calculus, factorial

$$\int_0^{\infty} x^{t-1} e^{-x}  \, \mathrm{d}x = (t-1)! = \Gamma (t)$$
Is the expression $(t-1)!$ the actual result of integrating the gamma integral? Meaning, if you were to compute the integral through the standard integral computation techniques, would you end up with $(t-1)(t-2)(t-3)...$? If so, how do we integrate the following?:
$$\int t!  \, \mathrm{d}t = \int \int_0^{\infty} x^{t} e^{-x}  \, \mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: The notation $t!$ is usually used only when $t$ is a nonnegative integer.  The $\Gamma$ function, on the other hand, is defined for all $t$ (except for the poles at nonpositive integers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to obtain the recursion formula $\Gamma(t+1)=t\Gamma(t)$, i.e. 
$$ \int_0^\infty x^te^{-x}\,\mathrm dx = t\cdot \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx.$$
Then together with an explicit computatoin of $\Gamma(1)$, you obtain the result that $\Gamma(t)0(t-19!$ for $t\in\mathbb N$.

The integral $\int t!\,\mathrm dt$ doesn't make much sense unless you write it as $\int \Gamma(t+1)\,\mathrm dt$ and I am not aware of any nice result / closed formula for that (or a reason for there existing one)

Comment: Good answer, but I still wonder if there is a defined integral for it.